# SQL query to add or subtract values based on another field

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the net total of a column-- sounds simple. The problem is that some of the values should be negative, as are marked in a separate column. For example, the table below would yield a result of (4+3-5+2-2 = 2).  I've tried doing this with subqueries in the select clause, but it seems unnecessarily complex and difficult to expand when I start adding in analysis for other parts of my table. Any help is much appreciated!

```
Sign     Value
Pos        4
Pos        3
Neg        5
Pos        2
Neg        2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `CASE` statement should work in most versions of sql:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE
               WHEN t.Sign = 'Pos' THEN t.Value
               ELSE t.Value * -1
            END
          ) AS Total
FROM YourTable AS t
```

Comment: Right on, all these ideas helped but this structure is working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I've come across this kind of things many times and have never been able to understand it so far. I wonder if you could tell me: why do some people (you, for instance) tend to write `Value * -1` (or `Value * (-1)`) instead of just `-Value`? Does the former seem clearer than the latter or is there something unreliable or inefficient (in any sense) about `-Value` that I might be missing? I'd like to think about this as no more than a curiosity, but I do suspect it may be bothering me beyond that. :) +1 on the solution, by the way.

Comment: @AndriyM I think it all boils down to personal preference.  I could have used `-t.Value` to provide the same answer, I have just used the `* -1` approach for so long, it seems to be what I default to.

Comment: Ah, the diversity of personal preferences! When one is unable to grasp them, one can always have the enjoyment of marvelling at them. :) Appreciate your response, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(sign = 'Pos', Value, Value * (-1))) as total FROM table
```

Comment: better than my answer, saves another select :)

Answer (score 1):

I am adding rows from a single field in a table based on values from another field in the same table using oracle 11g as database and sql developer as user interface.

This works:

```
SELECT COUNTRY_ID, SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN ACCOUNT IN 'PTBI' THEN AMOUNT
        WHEN ACCOUNT IN 'MLS_ENT' THEN AMOUNT
        WHEN ACCOUNT IN 'VAL_ALLOW' THEN AMOUNT
        WHEN ACCOUNT IN 'RSC_DEV' THEN AMOUNT * -1
    END) AS TI
FROM SAMP_TAX_F4
GROUP BY COUNTRY_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a= sum(Value) where Sign like 'pos'
select b = sum(Value) where Signe like 'neg'
select total = a-b
```

this is abit sql-agnostic, since you didnt say which db you are using, but it should be easy to adapat it to any db out there.